# Json with strings and arrays to Map

Tags: java, jackson

Say i have

```
{
   "foo" : "bar",
   "other-foo": "baz",
   "list-foo" : [
      "x": "y",
      "w":"z"
    ]
}
```

How can I make this a `Map`? I know I can use jackson...But I can't really call this a `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, Object>` or`Map<String, List>` is there a nice clean way, or is the answer to make an object that represents this all the way down?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do with this? (And you ***could*** make it a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` - but that's not a great idea).

Comment: Just want to make it a map, so the service consumer can pull out the needed values.  Maybe the better idea is to define an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you do not provide a target Class or TypeReference**

- Jackson will automatically deserialize a json object into to a `Map<String,Object>`, actually implemented by a `LinkedHashMap<String,Object>` that preserves the order of properties found in the JSON.
- There will be an entry in the map with key "list-foo" and a value that is `Map<String,Object>`.

**Or you can define specialized classes for Jackson to deserialize into.**

Jackson will deserialize into classes you define if it can.

If you provide a Class or a TypeReference to Jackson as a target, it will try to produce an instance of the requested class.

In general you can provide a class that meets one of these criteria

- The class is a bean with public setters that follow bean naming conventions.
- The class has public member fields that match the json property names.
- The class has public setter methods annotated with Jackson annotations.
- The class implements the interface JsonSerializable and has a serialize method.
- Or if you have created a custom serializer and associated it with the class using Jackson annotations.

Any member fields of the class can be deserialized too based on the same criteria or if they are primitive types, enums, or Java collections recognized by Jackson.